# reading contents from a webpage java

Tags: java, exception

```
URL u = new URL("http://java.sun.com/index.html");
URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
Scanner in = new Scanner(stream);
```

Using the above code may cause unchecked or checked exceptions. So I'm unsure what exceptions I should consider. checked exceptions occur no matter how careful you are and unchecked exceptions are runtime exceptions (usually)? So looking at each line of the above code, line 1 the URL may not exist, so would this be an unchecked exception, NoSuchElementExistsException? and line 2 URLconnection will open so long as the url is correct, so those two lines are coupled together...

Now I think the remaining 2 lines, InputStream and Scanner in are accounted for? Am I missing anything?

Comment: The javadoc is pretty clear about this. For unchecked exceptions, if you don't know which, just catch `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know which exception to catch, you can just catch everything.

```
try {
    URL u = new URL("http://java.sun.com/index.html");
    URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(stream); 
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    //Handle caught exception
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Netbeans, if you have a try-catch statement with catch(Exception e) it comes up with a warning symbol one the side and if you click it, it says something about multicatching exceptions. click and it comes changes Exception e to all the exceptions that can be thrown.